Google File Picker does not share the file with the app
The user is unable to share files with the app through the picker provided by Google Drive.
Function used to show the picker to select the file (the front-end is made in Angular):
connectGoogleDrive() {
    const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
      callback: (res: any) => {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
          const uuid = params.get('uuid');
          if (uuid != null && uuid.length > 0) {
            // send user UUID and refresh token/access token to the server
            this.apiService.connectToDrive(uuid, res.code).subscribe(response => {
              if (response.success && !response.error) {
                // server response is OK
                gapi.load('picker', () => {
                  const view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                    .setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST
                    .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.document,application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet,text/csv,text/plain,application/pdf')
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)
                    .setSelectFolderEnabled(false);

                  const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .setAppId(GOOGLE_APP_ID)
                    .setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY)
                    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                    .addView(view)
                    .setOAuthToken(response.data.access_token)
                    .setCallback((data: any) => {
                      console.log(data);
                      if (data.action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                        // send list of selected files to the server
                        this.apiService.putDriveFolder(uuid, { files: data.docs }).subscribe(response => {
                          this.loading = false;
                          if (response.success && !response.error) {
                            
                          } else {
                            console.error(response);
                          }
                        });

                      }
                    }).build();

                  picker.setVisible(true);
                });
              } else {
                console.error(response);
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.error('Invalid uuid');
          }
        });
      }
    });

    client.requestCode({ prompt: 'consent', access_type: 'offline' });
  }

From the backend (made in Python) only the files that the app creates are displayed:
// function called after files selection
def get_all_google_drive_files_new(access_token):
    // User access token obtained with the refresh token
    credentials = Credentials(token=access_token)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    results = service.files().list(fields="files(id,name)").execute()
    files = results.get('files', [])

    if not files:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for file in files:
            print(f"{file})")

From the google documentation I read that the scope I'm using, i.e. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, also allows the user to share files which the app can then open and read ("or that the user shares with an app while using the Google Picker API")
I tried entering the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive and indeed I get all the user's files but this requires an app verification and I don't need it. I don't understand why the user is not able to share files with my app.
I also tried to create the permissions as shown here, but with the scope I use, if you select a file not created by the app the 404 error returns.
What do I need? I need the user to be able to share a file with my app so that I can read it from the server

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The picker only responds with certain data... not the files themselves.  I think this is the reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/reference/results  Client-side the user would have to download them and then choose them to be uploaded.  You might see if you can download those files server-side... but that surely would require you to register the server-side app... and would probably require the user to make those files publicly accessible or specifically accessible to your app.

Did you find a solution?
